# Why can I not add background image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add the background image on my webapp but the background doesn't show up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Webapp</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("MUIC_campus.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        }
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        .btn-primary {
            background-color: #6a0dad;
            border-color: #6a0dad;
        }
        .btn-primary:hover {
            background-color: #550a8a;
            border-color: #550a8a;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 my-auto">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p>${error}</p>
            <form action="/login" method="post">
                <div class="input-group mb-4 input-group-md">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="username" style="width:40px">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username"
                           aria-describedby="username">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-4 input-group-md">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="password" style="width:40px">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"
                           aria-label="Password"
                           aria-describedby="password">
                </div>
                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

My `login.jsp` is already in the same folder as `MUIC_campus.jpg`.

[image]

I try to fix it but the background still blank. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can anyone guide me, I would really appreciate it?

Comment: Are you sure that the folder `WEB-INF` is actually being served as the root of your app?

Comment: Are you seeing any error in your browser devtools inspect facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WEB-INF node is not part of the public document tree of the application.
A file in WEB-INF cannot be sent to the browser.

Put your public files in webapp/assets.

After that you can access it:  background-image: url("assets/MUIC_campus.jpg");

.